# Search for the key in the given array of objects and replace the value;

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, underscore.js, arrays

Implementing the multiple sort functionality; Where need to toggle the array which hold the sorting fieldname and sorting order;

Example

Click Sort By Name:

```
[{"sortKey":"name","sortValue":"desc"}]
```

Again Click Sort By Name:

```
[{"sortKey":"name","sortValue":"asc"}]
```

Click Sort By Age:

```
[{"sortKey":"name","sortValue":"asc"},{"sortKey":"age","sortValue":"desc"} ]
```

Again Click Sort By Name:

```
[{"sortKey":"name","sortValue":"desc"},{"sortKey":"age","sortValue":"desc"} ]
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPyU71Mwzeg9xMlNENCn?p=preview)

```
if (checkIfObjectExists($scope.sortList, sortingObject)) {
    if (!$scope.sortList.hasOwnProperty(sortingObject.sortType)) {
        console.log($scope.sortList);
        // replace the value for the key
    }
} else {
    $scope.sortList.push(sortingObject);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to ask, I'm not getting.

Comment: Find the key:value pair in the array and if the key matches replace the value.

Comment: can you update the question with a simple example

Comment: Already I have posted a demo link where I able to push value to array but not able to replace the value for the key...

Comment: please edit your question so that it would be clear on what you're asking.

Comment: I've added what I think should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed some things in your implementation. Problem was you were checking if the whole object is not same then push in the array. But what you need if `sorKey` is same reverse the `sortValue`.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/78FVh/1/)

Changed your function `checkIfObjectExists` to `updateArray`.

```
function updateArray(array, newObject) {
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      var object = array[i];
      if (object.sortKey == newObject.sortKey) {
        object.sortValue= (object.sortValue==='asc')?'desc':'asc';
        return;
      }
    }
    array.push(newObject);
  }
```

And while calling I will just call like this in `$scope.clickMe`.

```
updateArray($scope.sortList, sortingObject);
```

Comment: I don't have a plunker account otherwise I've updated your one.